# Error with Exchange Web Services Subscription - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, ssl, exchangewebservices

I'm creating a subscription to a MS Exchange Inbox using the [ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) and JDK11 but I'm getting `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error`

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

code

```
public class EwsClient implements DisposableBean {
    private final ExchangeService exchangeService;
    private final int subscriptionLifetimeMinutes;
    private final List<Closeable> closeables = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor

    public void subscribe(Collection<FolderId> folderIds, EventType[] eventTypes, INotificationEventDelegate eventHandler) throws EwsException {
        try {
            StreamingSubscription subscription = exchangeService.subscribeToStreamingNotifications(folderIds, eventTypes);
            StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(exchangeService, subscriptionLifetimeMinutes);

            // keep the subscription alive by reconnecting to the Exchange server
            ISubscriptionErrorDelegate disconnectHandler = (sender, args) -> {
                try {
                    connection.open();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Could not reconnect to the exchange server", e);
                }
            };
            connection.addSubscription(subscription);
            connection.addOnNotificationEvent(eventHandler);
            connection.addOnDisconnect(disconnectHandler);
            connection.open();
            closeables.add(connection);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new EwsException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        for (Closeable closeable : closeables) {
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Error closing", e);
            }
        }
        exchangeService.close();
    }
}
```

stack trace

```
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:729) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:639) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:62) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:988) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:136) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flush(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:144) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.close(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:93) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:157) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123) ~[httpcore-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.HttpClientWebRequest.executeRequest(HttpClientWebRequest.java:292) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:720) ~[ews-java-api-2.0.jar:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:351) ~[na:na]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:320) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[na:na]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by reducing the `subscriptionLifetimeMinutes` value (in StreamingSubscriptionConnection constructor) from 15 minutes to 2 minutes. According to the [EWS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange) subscription connections can be open for up to 30 minutes. It's likely that there's a rule in my network which is closing the connection before that.